# How do I get python to print 'you lose' when i roll over 21 on my dice number generator?

Tags: python

I'm trying to create (basically) a random number generator where you "roll a dice" and python returns the number you roll, but if your total from all your rolls goes over 21, it prints 'you lose'. the random generator part works fine but i cant figure out the over 21 part. any ideas?

```
import random

dice = ["1","2","3","4","5","6"]
total = [random.choice(dice)]

diceroll = input("would you like to roll the die? please type yes or no.")

while diceroll == "yes":
  print ("you rolled", random.choice(dice))
  diceroll = input("would you like to roll the die? please type yes or no.")

# this section (above) tells me what number i have rolled
  if 21 < len(total):
    print ("you lose")

# this is what i have tried (above) for the over 21 section

if diceroll == "no":
  print ("goodbye")
```

Comment: create a variable add the each roll of dice value to it and then check if it is greater than 21 or not

Comment: for your info your code will not work as you expected `total` always will be a list with single element and why are you using string numbers?

Answer (score 1):

try that out:

```
import random

tries = []
while True:
    diceroll = input("would you like to roll the die? please type yes or no.")
    if diceroll == 'no':
        print('You said NO')
        break
    number = int(random.choice(range(1, 7)))
    tries.append(number)
    print("you rolled", number)
    if sum(tries) > 21:
        print("you loss")
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to correct the "total" variable in order for it to be a sum of dice throws. For now, it only records one throw.
Instead of assigning a new value, you need to use append() on an already existing list.
And also correct your dice numbers to integer format, as otherwise, sum() function wouldn't work.

```
dice = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
throws = list()

# Then calculate a sum of dice throws
while diceroll == "yes":
   throws.append(random.choice(dice))
   total = sum(throws)

   if 21 < total:
       print('you lose!')
```

Comment: I dont think this will work. choice will pick one of the 6 numbers. The sum will always be less than 21. Can you improve the code so it is more clear. If this is inside a loop, you are resetting throws each time. So append has no value

Comment: You're right, I updated my code wrapping it correctly into a while loop.

Answer (score 0):

Here's code that does what you're trying to do in a more straightforward and standard way.  I didn't know what to do with your check for a "loss", so I just left that kinda hanging:

```
import random

total = 0

while True:
    inp = input("would you like to roll the die? please type yes or no.")
    if inp.lower() == 'no':
        break
    if inp.lower() != 'yes':
        continue
    roll = random.randint(1, 6)
    total += roll
    print ("you rolled", roll, "and your total is", total)
    if 21 < total:
        print ("you lose")
print ("goodbye")
```

Sample output:

```
would you like to roll the die? please type yes or no.yes
you rolled 3 and your total is 3
would you like to roll the die? please type yes or no.yes
you rolled 3 and your total is 6
would you like to roll the die? please type yes or no.yes
you rolled 4 and your total is 10
would you like to roll the die? please type yes or no.yes
you rolled 6 and your total is 16
would you like to roll the die? please type yes or no.yes
you rolled 6 and your total is 22
you lose
would you like to roll the die? please type yes or no.asdf
would you like to roll the die? please type yes or no.asdf
would you like to roll the die? please type yes or no.yes
you rolled 4 and your total is 26
you lose
would you like to roll the die? please type yes or no.yes
you rolled 2 and your total is 28
you lose
would you like to roll the die? please type yes or no.yes
you rolled 3 and your total is 31
you lose
would you like to roll the die? please type yes or no.no
goodbye
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the **random.choice** method inside the loop to keep track of the sum. Also, declare the dice list in integer.

```
dice=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
number=[]
diceroll = input("would you like to roll the die? please type yes or no.")
while diceroll == "yes":
  number.append(random.choice(dice))
  print ("you rolled",number[-1])
  if sum(number)>21:
    print('You lose!')
    break
  diceroll = input("would you like to roll the die? please type yes or no.")
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling the `random.choice(dice)` *in* the `print` statement, you'll need to store the returned value of the `random.choice(dice)` into a variable so that it can be accessed more than once:

```
while diceroll == "yes":
  roll = random.choice(dice)
  print("you rolled", roll)
```

Now, you can append the `roll` variable into the `total` list and increase the length of the `total` list:

```
  total.append(roll)
```

---

Note, if you won't be using the values inside the `total` list, and only defined the list to count the number of rolls, you can instead replace the `while` loop with a `for` loop like so:

```
for _ in range(20):
  print ("you rolled", random.choice(dice))
  diceroll = input("would you like to roll the die? please type yes or no.")

  if diceroll == "no":
    print ("goodbye")
    break

else:
    print ("you lose")
```

The above `else` statement gets executed if the `break` statement never met, meaning the `for` loop ended because it ran out of iterations.